# "Qu'est-ce que c'est?" vs "Qu'est-ce que c'est que ça?"

Tags: registre

I have seen both and am uncertain what difference there is. As far as I understand, both mean *What's that?* or *What is it?*

What is the difference? Is either preferable, or is one of them slang?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Qu'est-ce que c'est?* is your regular *What's that?*, not very formal, but not specially familiar neither.

*Qu'est-ce que c'est que ça?* is less formal, and bears a sense either of negativity, anger, or surprise. It could be translated into *What's that thing?*.

On the other side of the spectrum, you could use the very formal *Qu'est-ce?* or *Qu'est-ce donc?*.

Comment: If I said something crazy like *Quelle est cette chose?* would that be blatantly weird?

Comment: Depending on the context, it might be plain weird, or too formal. I honestly don't see a context where this expression would be chosen over the others, at least orally.

Comment: Worst case scenario, one would say “*Qu’est-ce [que c’est que] cette chose ?*”. If you want to go less formal, I would say “C’est quoi ?” for “What’s that?” and “C’est quoi ce truc ?” for “What’s that thing?”.

Comment: Wouldn't you say "*Qu'est-ce que cette chose?*" rather than "*Qu'est-ce cette chose?*" ? The latter seems pretty unnatural to pronounce...